# SQL-Deadlock using EF 6

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, entity-framework-6

I have an import routine, that imports a lot of data from my ERP into my SQL-Database. I'm importing the data in batches of 20. The imported IDs coming from my ERP are compared with the ones from my Database. Based on that, I'm either inserting or updating entries from my DB:

```
        private static async Task ImportWorkOrderBatch(
            List<DataEntryStruct> batch,
            ESBClient client,
            SemaphoreSlim esbLimiter,
            SemaphoreSlim dbLimiter,
            ResourceMapper resourceMapper,
            SmlStorage smlStorage,
            string clsNamesToImport,
            string language,
            ConcurrentBag<string> issueList)
        {
            using DatabaseEntities db = new();

            db.Database.CommandTimeout = ImportDatabaseTimeout;

            // Get and apply changes
            {
                Dictionary<string, WorkOrder> existingWorkOrders;
                dsyWorkOrder05TtyWorkOrder[] esbResults;

                // Gather all required data
                {
                    Task<Dictionary<string, WorkOrder>> getExistingWorkOrdersTask = GetBatchFromDb(db, dbLimiter, batch);
                    Task<dsyWorkOrder05TtyWorkOrder[]> getEsbDataTask = GetBatchFromEsb(batch, client, esbLimiter, clsNamesToImport, language, issueList);

                    // Wait for all data to arrive
                    await Task.WhenAll(getExistingWorkOrdersTask, getEsbDataTask);

                    existingWorkOrders = getExistingWorkOrdersTask.Result;
                    esbResults = getEsbDataTask.Result;
                }

                // Iterate over ESB results
                foreach (dsyWorkOrder05TtyWorkOrder currentDetail in esbResults)
                {
                    WorkOrder currentWorkOrder;

                    if (!existingWorkOrders.TryGetValue(currentDetail.Obj, out currentWorkOrder) || currentWorkOrder == null)
                    {
                        currentWorkOrder = new WorkOrder();

                        db.WorkOrders.Add(currentWorkOrder);
                    }

                    // Set regular fields
                    await currentWorkOrder.ApplyTtyWorkOrder(currentDetail, resourceMapper, smlStorage, language);
                }

                // Deleted entries that have been removed from ProAlpha
                DeleteOldWorkOrders(batch, existingWorkOrders, esbResults);
            }

            // Store batch changes to database
            try
            {
                await dbLimiter.WaitAsync();
                await db.SaveChangesUnattendedAsync();
            }
            finally
            {
                dbLimiter.Release();
            }
        }
```

Everything works fine until the code arrives in my `DeleteOldWorkOrders-Method`. When it comes to the scenario that a workOrder needs to be deleted and im trying to set the deleted field to true, I get this error:

> An exception has been raised that is likely due to a transient failure. If you are connecting to a SQL Azure database consider using SqlAzureExecutionStrategy.
> Inner exception 1: Transaction (Process ID 99) was deadlocked on lock | communication buffer resources with another process and has been chosen as the deadlock victim. Rerun the transaction.

My SQL Server Profiler says that there is a deadlock on my Update-Statement when setting Deleted = true. The query looks very basic. I can't seem to understand why this entry is locked by another process, it just gets selected and then updated. This is my DeleteOldWorkOrders-Method:

```
        private static void DeleteOldWorkOrders(List<DataEntryStruct> batch, Dictionary<string, WorkOrder> existingWorkOrders, dsyWorkOrder05TtyWorkOrder[] erpResults)
        {
            IEnumerable<string> providedObjIDs = erpResults
                .Select(wo => wo.Obj);

            IEnumerable<DataEntryStruct> workOrdersToDelete = batch
                .Where(wob => !providedObjIDs.Contains(wob.ObjID));

            foreach (DataEntryStruct dataEntry in workOrdersToDelete)
            {
                if (existingWorkOrders.TryGetValue(dataEntry.ObjID, out WorkOrder elementToDelete))
                {
                    elementToDelete.Deleted = true;
                }
            }
        }
```

I have tried to position this method somewhere else, call `SaveChangesAsync()` in other areas, even after the import routine, but it does not seem to work. Any help?

Comment: `await Task.WhenAll(getExistingWorkOrdersTask, getEsbDataTask);` You are concurrently querying the same db context. That is not supported by EF.

Comment: The question doesn't contain any EF code. EF uses optimistic concurrency and *doesn't* keep connections open at all. To get deadlocks you have to actually try *very* hard, by keeping connections open explicitly, eg by using external transactions. It's not thread safe because it *doesn't* need to be - EF is a Unit-of-Work, persisting all pending changes, not a database connection. The very fact tasks are involved and the existence of `dbLimiter.Release();` suggest the missing application code is misusing EF and using long-lived transactions

Comment: To diagnose a deadlock we'd need at a minimum: the generated SQL queries from EF that are deadlocking, the tables and index definitions involved, the deadlock XDL/XML graph and please share the query plans via https://brentozar.com/pastetheplan. This question is not answerable otherwise.

Comment: EF is not made for this kind of thing. You are better off using classes from the `System.Data.SqlClient` namespace and making use of set operations.

Comment: @Silvermind, Of the two tasks, only one is using the DbContext, this looks to be loading 2 sources, one from DbContext the other from another data source.

A deadlock is not likely going to have the cause and effect revealed in this method. Given these reads and saves are asynchronous, the question needs to look at what else is running in the database while this is happening and what isolation level your database is running, and existence of anything like Tx Scopes. Why a semaphore when you are scoping a DbContext instance wiithn this method?

Comment: @StevePy You're right. I was thrown off, because of the `WhenAll` red flag. Sure it is usable, but it always jumps out to me when db context operations are involved. This might also suggest something could be wrong in `GetBatchFromDb`.

Comment: Thanks for your answers, unfortunately this process and my DB is huge, so it would be a little too much to share everything. This is of course also part of the problem. I have now located the Delete-Method after the whole routine with a new DbContext and rewrote it a little and now it works. Thats not exactly how I wanted it to solve but I spent way too much time on this..